# Filebased lookup table

Tags: .net, io, nosql

I have a large number of sequential integers i need to do a lookup on, ie I need to get an offset for an serial integer id. The problem is that I'd rather not load the entire table into memory to build a hashtable/dictionary due to memory constraints so what to do?

One solution that might work is to have a file where the first integer stored is the lowest id used, then you write an array of zero integers one for each id to the largest (appending when needed)  and write in the id at the correct position. For instance if the lowest id is 1000 and you want to fetch the offset at 20000 you simply retrieve the integer at position 10000+20000-1.

Using memory mapping this technique should perform pretty well. Have anyone had a similar problem, is this a good solution or is there any better way?

Comment: How often will the data change?

Comment: Id's will be appended to it serially (there might be some slight gaps) which might be filled later on but generally when an id is set it's set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [B-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_Tree), which is specifically optimized for use on hard disks.

B-Trees are used by almost all modern databases and filesystems.

Comment: Ah interesting. If there were large gaps in the id's B-Tree's might be the way to go so as not have to store excessive amount of empty keys, but I don't see the advantage they'd offer here since you would have to do a search than a straight lookup

Comment: @MattiasK: If you update the data frequently, a B-Tree will be better.  If you never update it, your idea would probably be best.

Comment: A b-tree won't require a full scan for any single item, it's an O(log n) operation to traverse the intermediate nodes in order to find the appropriate leaf node. B-tree searches are fast enough in most cases that you should never need a full scan of the b-tree's leaf nodes. You can make further optimizations to how you're storing the data and use a B+-tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can always go for a database. SQLite can be used if you do not need multiple applications/processes accessing the data. This automatically creates indexes for you and allows you to use SQL queries to retrieve information.

Comment: Thanks, I know what a database is, don't let the nosql tag fool you ;)

Comment: I supposed you would :P. The question then that arises is: why doesn't this fit your need? The reason I suggest this is that it looks like a fitting solution is because it's a B-Tree solution where the work is done for you.